How to reconcile faith & biblical scholarship?
One thing that makes me doubt is contemporary biblical scholarship consensus and academic biblical teachings. Some of their teachings are irreconcilable with faith.
Yes Im flirting with becoming an evangelical Fundie & I would love the bible to be literally perfect & infallible. But even if one is not a evangelical Fundie it should matter if the bible on the whole is correct. Because Jesus confirmed the Old Testament & by denying this the New Testament and Jesus gift of eternal life is invalid, too.
I know there are also conservative scholars but those are not many and the scholarly consensus  is eating them up alive.
To dismiss biblical scholar consensus as theories without proof seems too easy and also unfair bc its a science in which loads of hard work was done and many people brooded over it a long time.

The Bible cannot replace God. It is a writing of men, just as your writing. When God destroyed the temple itself by saying I do not dwell in temples, we must not fall on the same trap of the flesh to go back into temples and idols like bible worship or any kind of presuppositionism, since God is truth/logos reason not an idol https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/11286/why-is-literary-style-not-inspired/100105#100105

Some of these biblical scholarship groups analyze the scriptures with an initial understanding that they will not consider any supernatural interpretations.
Whatever conclusions they come to will of course reflect this position.
¶Your question could be improved by providing quotations and citations of some "scholarly" quotations that cause you problems.

A lot of liberal biblical scholarship rejects out of hand the notion of God, miracles, prophets, etc and attempts to arbitrarily pick and choose which details they are going to consider worthy of consideration. So it’s good to be critical of the assumptions that such research makes. On the other hand, fundamentalism is primarily rooted in the seeking the same false sense of self-assuredness as Catholics when they declared the pope infallible. The bible was transcribed, transmitted, translated, canonized, and interpreted by fallible men. Obviously there are going to be errors. Be diligent.

It seems a little ironic, but you appear to have a very strong faith in statements about what the scholarly consensus is. In reality consensus is rarely reached in theology. For example, something like the New Perspective on Paul is very influential and widely studied, but probably the biggest consensus it actually led to was that we can't ignore the Jewish 1st century context of Paul. But what that means for our interpretations of Paul is still highly debated. Most claims of scholarly consensus don't come with evidence, so take them with a grain of salt.

There are plenty of resources that affirm fundamentalist views like creationism, KJV-only, Biblical infallibility and accuracy, etc.
If this is for apologetics, you may need to search deeper, but just for yourself, you can use popular sources like Answers in Genesis or GotQuestions Ministry.
If you need extra help, I would recommend you talk to your local IFB Pastor. You can trust that their teaching is Biblically based, and not heretical.
God with be with ye!

I would humbly submit that the works of the modern scholars are done in a more intellectual method, and not with a spiritual method. This is what causes your mental conflict here. You see modern scholars using massively elegant rationality and reason, the gift of God our intellect... but then it seems faith is lost somewhere.

The majority of the church is based on the Catholic church, which has accepted "Thomism" as a type of basis. One of the main things within Thomism is that you can demonstrate that God exists by reason. And generally this type of "reasoning" has remained within the western churches (catholic, protestant, etc)
This is in contrast to the early church fathers and the Orthodox Church who are more like St. Gregory Palamas. Palamite theology is historically often rejected due to the mystical nature of it. (specifically the practices used by hesychasts to achieve theosis were characterized as "magic")

So I believe your issue is that you see all of this modern "theology" which is done in an academic pursuit style (kinda like this website). That is very Thomistic.
Consider the eastern orthodox perspective and see if it resolves your dilemma. For us we do not treat theology as an academic pursuit, it is based on revelation. It is validated by ascetic pursuits and not academic degrees or scholasticism.
This is based on the assertion that "one cannot be genuine or a true theologian or teach knowledge of God, without having experienced God, as is defined as the vision of God (Theoria)."

Saint Gregory insists that to theologize "is permitted only to those who have passed examinations and have reached theoria, and who have been previously purified in soul and body, or at least are being purified.

You would have to delve much deeper into this subject to decide of course... and of course we can use our minds. But our minds alone will not reach God. That is the faith part you are looking for.

Here is a quick rundown of basic concepts within Orthodox Theology (which is Palamite)

Theosis, the quintessential purpose and goal of Christian life is to attain theosis or 'deification' which is understood as "likeness to" or "union with" god. It is a process, and refers to the original "likeness" of humans and God. (We are made in the image or likeness of God) It is the gradual submission to the Truth (God)

Theoria, is the state of illumination on the path to theosis, in which one beholds God. To reach this we need Hesychasm (contemplative prayer) resulting from the cultivation of watchfulness (nepsis). In the purest form, theoria is "seeing" or "vision" of God. Which happens when our mind is calm we are able to see better. Theoria as an experience of God (who is unknowable and cannot be experienced) happens to the whole person (nous/soul), not just the mind or body, which is in contrast to an experience of God that is drawn from memory, the mind or in time. (Like the LDS have, they have mind/body experiences but not Theoria)

Hesychasm: Is based on "Matthew 6:6" where we are instructed to go into our room or closet and shut the door and pray to your father who is in secret. The Hesychast withdraws into solitude in order to reach a deeper state of contemplative stillness. It is also part of the attempt to reach "unceasing prayer" described by St. Paul the Apostle.

Tabor Light, refers to the light revealed on Mt. Tabor at the Transfiguration. It is also the light seen by Paul at his conversion. This refers to the uncreated energies of God. (the grace of God). Palamas taught that it is possible for believers to experience this as well.



You can see why it looks like mystical magical stuff from the western perspective right? But hey that is what faith looks like to science and rationality sometimes.
